# How to pronounce ''Water 6 X 1.5 Litre''

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

It says on the tag '' Water 6 X 1.5 Litre'' . While pronouncing this phrase can i say : '' six bottles of 1,5 liter of water '' . Would it be correct or not ?

Comment: It's not wrong, but I think it would be more common to hear "six one-point-five-liter bottles of water" or "six one-and-a-half-liter bottles of water".

Answer (score 1):

"X" represents the *multiplication symbol*, sometimes spoken as "*times*". 'In some contexts, it isn't spoken at all, and we would just say what it means using common language. The same is true of most abbreviations - we read what it *means* rather than what it says.

"6 x 1.5 litre" means that, inside the package, there are 6 bottles, each with 1.5litre of water inside.

I would probably "read" that label as "six, one-and-a-half-litre bottles of water".

As an aside, it is worth noting that in computing, the asterisk usually substitutes for the multiplication symbol, as computer keyboards do not contain the correct mathematical symbol for multiplication. Although the true symbol does resemble the letter 'x', it should be a rotationally symmetric cross, whereas many fonts render the letter 'x' asymmetrically.

Comment: In "list" type contexts (speaker is reeling off a list of items on a purchase order, for example), there's often a convention whereby the actual *quantity* for each line item is specificed *last*. Thus *one-and-a-half-litre bottles of water, **six of***. But I've also heard ***...six OFF*** in such contexts. Dunno if the allusion is to *...to be taken **off** the shelf and delivered* or something like that. Or maybe it relates to usages like *This is a **one off** special purchase.*

Comment: You might also hear "it's a six pack of one and a half liter water bottles" assuming we're referring to a package that hasn't been opened.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be wrong to say 'six bottles of 1,5 liter of water' as that is what the product is. People often do not read what is literally on a label, for example a bottle might say 1l, but people will say one liter.

An alternate way to read the label is "Water 6 by 1.5 liter" or "6 by 1.5 liter of Water"